# Getting "collection already exists" in Solr logging when creating collection through java code

Tags: java, spring-boot, solr, airflow, solrcloud

I have 8 solr(8.2.0 version) servers and 5 ZooKeepers (3.4.14 version) in my project.

I am creating solr collections programmatically using spring boot and running some backend logic. I am running this spring boot code on a schedule basis using airflow 5 times a day. In a day the collection name is unique something like 'name_20200805' for all 5 schedules in a day. So for the first schedule run when the collection is getting created i am getting the below error even though collection is getting created for first time on that day. If collection already exists i am skipping creating the collection for other 4 schedules in a day.

schedule for airflow is `airflow_dag 0 2,4,6,8,10 * * *` . this schedule is PDT timings. The spring boot jar is runing in databricks.

method used to create the collection:

```
boolean doProcess(Record record) {
        Record outputRecord = record.copy();

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYYMMdd");
        String newCollectionName = "name"+ "_" + LocalDate.now().format(formatter);

        CloudSolrClient solr = new CloudSolrClient.Builder(zkHost, Optional.empty()).build();

        List<String> currentCollections = currentCollections(solr);
        if(!currentCollections.contains(newCollectionName)) {
            if (createTimestampedCollection(newCollectionName, solr)) {
                //some code here
            }
        }
        outputRecord.put("solrCollection", newCollectionName);

        try {
            solr.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return super.doProcess(outputRecord);
    }


boolean createTimestampedCollection(String newCollectionName, CloudSolrClient solr) {
        final CollectionAdminRequest.Create createCollection = CollectionAdminRequest.Create.createCollection(newCollectionName, configSet, numShards, numReplicas);
        createCollection.setBasicAuthCredentials(username, password);
        createCollection.setMaxShardsPerNode(numReplicas);
        CollectionAdminResponse adminResponse = null;
        try {
            adminResponse = createCollection.process(solr);
        } catch (SolrServerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Can someone help me to fix the below issue

```
Collection: name_20200805 operation: create failed:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: collection already exists: name_20200805
at org.apache.solr.cloud.api.collections.CreateCollectionCmd.call(CreateCollectionCmd.java:116)
at org.apache.solr.cloud.api.collections.OverseerCollectionMessageHandler.processMessage(OverseerCollectionMessageHandler.java:264)
at org.apache.solr.cloud.OverseerTaskProcessor$Runner.run(OverseerTaskProcessor.java:505)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:209)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Unless anyone sees your code, its difficult to understand the cause of the issue

Comment: Well, the collection already exists. Could be an issue with time zones - where you're running the script on the day before (your local time), but the UTC time (which might be what Java is giving you back) already has rolled over; making sure that you're effectively attempting to create the collection from the day before. Or you might be invoking collection creation multiple times; or Airflow may run several instances if one doesn't terminate correctly (the log should show each task being invoked iirc). Add code.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please check the code